# Is this a vector of vectors?

Tags: c++, vector

I was looking at some code and noticed this:

```
vector<int> V[10000];
```

and then later

```
V[index].push_back(value);
```

Is this the same as "`vector< vector<int> >`"?

Comment: A vector of vectors can be resized. `V` cannot be resized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an array of `vector<int>`s.

You can't call `V.push_back`.